# How to post a string array using Async POST request in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

My input is a string array and I cant find how to async post request in C# .net

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.baseServiceURL);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new  MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(application/json));

var content = new StringContent(arr1.tostring());
//Make Rest API Get Method call                  
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
 public async void AsyncPost()
        {
            string[] values= new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };

            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
           Values= values
            });

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync("http://SomeUrl.somewhere", content);

                    if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        // Do something...
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            }
        }
```

Comment: FormUrlEncodedContent doesnt work. It takes only name/value pair as inputs. Any other suggestion?

Comment: please i have made some edit check it and give me feedback.

Comment: For performance considerations, it's best to reuse already created instance of HttpClient instead of disposing it every call by "using(HttpClient)".

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your input if you want to use `application/json` as `Content-Type`.

I strongly suggest you to use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) on your client to serialize you array into a json string:

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr1), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

As an alternative, you could serialize your string array manually:

```
var serialized = "[" + string.Join(",", arr1.Select(v => "\"" + v + "\"")) + "]";
var content = new StringContent(serialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

But I discourage you in using such a error-prone approach.

---

#### Side note:

Depending on the .NET Framework version you are using, you could add the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package and use [`HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasjsonasync.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method letting the framework do the heavy lifting:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, arr1);
```